# Removing EFI partition from external Disk?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, diskutil

A few months ago I decided to format an external HD that I wish to use with my Mac mini, but I can not use 100% of it.

In the formatting process, a partition called EFI appeared. When I open the Disk Utility app, the partition is not displayed, but it was displayed by the command line using `diskutil`.

Here is the Disk Utility:

[image]

From the command line: `diskutil list`

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS MAC HD                  881.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:         Microsoft Reserved                         16.8 MB    disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                118.9 GB   disk0s4

/dev/disk1 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *640.1 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data HD Caio                 639.9 GB   disk1s2
```

How can I recover the space lost to **disk1s1**?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

EFI partition is a partition that stores boot files for operating systems, but since it is an external drive, it's not needed. When you erase your disk and create a new GUID Partitioning Table on it, macOS will automatically create an EFI partition. If you don't want that EFI partition, you have a few options:

- You can erase your disk and create a new MBR instead of GPT. To do this, follow these steps:

  1. Open Terminal. You can use spotlight to find it
  2. Make sure your external disk is inserted. Type `diskutil list` and identify your disk (in the output you provided, it looks like it's `disk1`).
  3. Type `diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ MYDISK MBR diskX` and replace `diskX` with the actual disk's identifier (for example, `disk1`)
  4. Your disk will be erased without an EFI partition now.
- You can use diskpart.exe to partition the disk on Windows. Windows doesn't create an EFI partition.

Comment: I ran the command and the EFI partition simply disappeared instead of going back to the disk:

/dev/disk1 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *640.1 GB   disk1
   1:                  Apple_HFS MYDISK                  640.1 GB   disk1s1

Comment: Should not partitions `disk1s1` and `disk1s2` merge?

Comment: What do you mean? It looks like it's solved.

Comment: They did. It was 639.9 GB and it merged with 200 MB so it's now 640.1 GB.

Comment: There is a limit on the size of volume that MBR and APM can used on. I know that 4TB is too large. Essentially, for modern drive sizes, there is only one format... GPT, and it appears there is no way to remove the EFI partition and reclaim that space.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, In Mac Terminal

Step 1. type command to **get list of partitions**

```
diskutil list
```

Step 2. to **erase/remove EFI partition**

```
diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ MYDISK MBR disk2
```

*Note :* *MyDisk is new name for your drive and disk to is the drive partition*

Step 3. that,s it.. just check your new structure

```
diskutil list
```

**EFI partition is gone!!**

Step 4. Now remove your drive(USB) and connect to PC

Step 5. Just Format in normal way and start using.

Comment: Can't use MBR format on large single partition HDDs